# How efficient is my Rock Paper Scissors?

Tags: java

So I'm fairly new to Java, and in the class I'm taking we had to make Rock Paper Scissors. It didn't seem too hard so I wanted to make it use the fewest possible IF statements. Is there a better way for me to do it?

FYI: `Syso = System.out.println()`
I used Scanner
I'm typing this on a phone sorry for any formatting errors.

LOGIC (typed this in notepad)

Rock is 1 paper is 2 scissors are 3.
User Input - CPU = Sum & Result

Rock - Scissors = -2 You Win
Rock - Paper = -1 You Lose

Paper - Rock = 1 You Win
Paper - Scissors = -1 You Lose

Scissors - Paper = 1 You Win
Scissors - Rock = 2 You Lose

= 0 Always tie

CODE (done in eclipse but typed from mobile also excluding stuff like using scanner and setting up variables)

Input = Input - CPU

```
If (input == 0){
    Syso "You Tied"
}
Else
{
    If (input == -1){
        Syso "You Lose"
    }
    If (input == 1){
        Syso "You Win"
    }
    If (input == 2){
        Syso "You Lose"
    }
    If (input == -2){
        Syso "You Win"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please improve the formatting. Use code-tags to properly format code. Also, if you can't type it completely because you're on your phone, why not wait until you get home and can give it your full attention?

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com would probably be a better site for such question.

Comment: You could trivially remove two of the input comparisons. Or use none with a switch. Or remove *all* of it with a horribly over-engineered object-only approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try multi conitional if statments with the && and ||

```
if ( i = 0 )  s.out.println("its a tie");
else if ( i == -1 || i == 2 )  s.out.println("you lost");
else if ( i == 1 || i == -2 )  s.out.println("you won");
```

if you have no other posibble outcome, you could leave te last check to only

```
else  s.out.println("you won");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (input == 0)
{ 
    Syso "You Tied"; 
} 
else if (input < 0){
    Syso "You lose";
}
else {
    Syso "you win";
}
```

You should keep paper as 1, sccissors as 2, and rock 3. That way -ve cases will be lose cases and +ve cases will be win cases. This code has lesser number of comparisons.

Comment: `input == -2` should also return `Syso "you win"`

Comment: this looks like a good fix, problem is : `i < 1 = 0`, `-1` and `-2`.. but the case gave `-2 = win` and `1 = win`. (just a minor thing, why evaluate 0? just do  `<= -1` )

Comment: Edited, it was a typo.